# Existence of continuous function so that given two functions satisfies a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Do there exists continuous functions p,q on $(-a,a), a>0,$ such that the functions
$y_1(x)=x^2\sin{x}$ and $y_2=1-\cos{x}$ satisfies the equation $$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0 $$ on this interval.

I assumed that for some $ p,q$ it does. But these two function's Wronskian is $0$ at $x=0$. but they do not seem linearly independent as they aren't constant multiple of each other.

Is it good enough.

Comment: The implications of [Abel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity) lead me to believe no.

Comment: You can even show more: just ignore $y_2$ and prove that there is no ODE of that form such that $y_1$ satisfies it. How? The function $y_1$ would then satisfy the IVP \begin{equation*}\begin{cases}y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0\\ y(0)=y'(0)=0,\end{cases}\end{equation*} whose unique solution is the function constantly equal to zero.